# On derivatives...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a quick question here. I hope someone can help. I haven't done calculus for a long time so I seem to missed out on details.

If $x=g^{-1}(y)$ and $g$ is monotonic and is differentiable for all $x$, how did it happen that $$\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=\frac{1}{dg(x)/dx}|_{x=g^{-1}(y)}$$

I tried to reason out that $$\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}x=\frac{dx}{dy}$$ But I do not know where to proceed. I hope someone helps. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to prove the formula for the derivative of the *inverse function* of a bijective one?

Comment: This can be seen to be a consequence of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), provided you already happen to know that $g^{-1}$ is well-defined and differentiable. For a broader context, I'd follow @DonAntonio's suggestion and look into the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlights:

$$y=g(x)\implies x=g^{-1}(y)$$

so let us denote $\;g(x_0):=y_0\;$ , and assuming what must be assumed (*what?* For example, $\;g'(x_0)\neq 0\;$ ...!) , we get:

$$\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y_0):=\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{g^{-1}(y)-g^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0}=\lim_{g(x)\to g(x_0)}\frac{x-x_0}{g(x)-g(x_0)}=\frac1{g'(x_0)}$$

since, by continuity of $\;g^{-1}\;$ , we have that $\;g(x)=y\to y_0=g(x_0)\implies x\to x_0\;$

Comment: How did this happen? $$\frac{d}{dy}g(y_0):=\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{g^{-1}(y)-g^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0}$$ Isn't it supposed to be $$\frac{d}{dy}g(y_0):=\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{g(y)-g(y_0)}{y-y_0}$$ And yes, $g$ is assumed to be bijective.

Comment: A simple typo: it is corrected now.

Comment: Ok @DonAntonio. I got to understand this better now. Thanks :)